# Is there a GUI to edit/add users and groups

Tags: gnome, users, administration, user-interface, multiuser

Is there a graphical tool that shows (edits) *all* users and groups on the system, so that one can avoid editing `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` directly?

[GNOME Settings](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center) (`gnome-control-center`) *Users* view lets only see desktop users and no groups at [all](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/user-accounts.html.en).

Comment: Have you tried kuser?

Comment: Just right now. Very similar to `system-config-users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs satisfying the requirements are:

- *Users and Groups* (`system-config-users`), developed by Red Hat, included in RHEL/CentOS 7, has SELinux build dependency, deprecated.[[1](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6251)][[2](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/system-config-users/)][[3](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/system-config-users/c/48b4e69d3301e78bae5828cd4db5bc1db2fca3dc?branch=master)]
- KUser (`kuser`), developed by KDE project, included in 4.x versions, unmantained.[[4](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1055308-start-0.html)]

Mostly identical, after installed they will be accessed under the `Users and Groups` (`KUser`) entry under `Sundry` (`System tools`) within the *Applications* menu.

Otherwise at the prompt type their `command_name` to get the user manager gui to pop up.

### Users and Groups (`system-config-users`)

[image: test]

Under preferences there is a checkbox for *hide system users & groups* so uncheck that to see everything listed in `/etc/passwd` within the gui.

#### Installation

**Archlinux**: [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/system-config-users/)

**CentOS**: available from the base install, but it not installed by default so you have to manually do a

```
yum install system-config-users
```

to have it available.

**Fedora**: *system-config-users* can be found as `system-config-users-1.3.5-4.el7.noarch.rpm` and can be freely obtained from one of the centos or fedora repositories.  And I think this can also obtained via doing (depending on the version)

```
yum groupinstall "Graphical Administration Tools"
```

**Suse**: I would use there `YAST - users` utility.

**Ubuntu**: [never](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=system-config-users) packaged it.

### KUser (`kuser`)

[image: KUser]

#### Installation

**Archlinux**: AUR [package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/system-config-users/).

## Other user management tools

They do not show *all* users/groups:

- **[Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/)**,
  the CentOS 8.x replacement to `system-config-users`.[[5](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libselinux/#comment-728942)]
- **[webmin](http://webmin.com/)**,
  more a system management tool for the browser than just an users/groups manager.
- **[Users and Groups](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Archive/gnome-system-tools) (`gnome-system-tools`)** lets you see all groups but not all users, while
- **[GNOME Settings](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center) (`gnome-control-center`)** only users and no groups.

## Related questions

- [How to manage users and groups using GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups-using-gui)
- [How to fully manage users and groups with web GUI and create templates for new users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251490/how-to-fully-manage-users-and-groups-with-web-gui-and-create-templates-for-new-u)
- [12.04 - How to add / list / remove a group - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404333/how-to-add-list-remove-a-group?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

### Users and groups (`system-config-users`)

`system-config-users` is a tool developed by Red Hat and included in **RHEL/CentOS 7**.

That is available from the base install, but it not installed by default so you have to manually do a

```
yum install system-config-users
```

to have it available.

That will then provide a `Users and Groups` entry under `Sundry` within the *Applications* menu.

Otherwise at the prompt type `system-config-users` to get this user manager gui to pop up.  Under preferences there is a checkbox for *hide system users & groups* so uncheck that to see everything listed in `/etc/passwd` within the gui.

#### RPM-based distros

*system-config-users* can be found as `system-config-users-1.3.5-4.el7.noarch.rpm` and can be freely obtained from one of the centos or fedora repositories.  And I think this can also obtained via doing

```
yum groupinstall "Graphical Administration Tools"
```

And if you are using SuSE then I would use there `YAST - users` utility.

#### Archlinux-based distros

There is an [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/system-config-users/).

#### Debian-based distros

Ubuntu provides a perl package named `gnome-system-tools` {which I am not familiar with}

Comment: Superthanks!
I have just made it into an ArchLinux [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/system-config-users).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as a KISS alternative: https://github.com/zhuyaliang/user-admin ("MATE User Manager").

It's on RPM as `mate-user-admin`. It doesn't seem to be packaged on Ubuntu.

Comment: It is the MATE fork of `gnome-system-tools`.

Comment: I think it's a clone, not an actual fork of the source code

Comment: It seems it has been forked from `gnome-system-tools` on 
[July 2018](https://github.com/zhuyaliang/user-admin/commit/e41dbd1443f5dd430d7f0d4e54c26994e492bfc8).